# Calling function in State from another file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have a flutter project that I am working on. I have a widget that I need to be able to rebuild (Stateful Widget). But the problem is, I also need to be able to have a variable that changes during its lifetime and a function that I can call from another file to change that variable.

card_place.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardPlace extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardPlace({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.slots,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String name;
  final String description;
  final int slots;

  @override
  State<CardPlace> createState() => _CardPlaceState();
}

class _CardPlaceState extends State<CardPlace> {
  int progress = 0;

  String get path => "assets/logos/${widget.name}.png";

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      progress++;
    });

    print(progress);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // boring front end; 
  }
}
```

card_manager.dart

```dart
List<CardPlace> cards = [];

dynamic findCard(String name) {
  for (var card in cards) {
    if (card.name == name) {
      return card;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

void updateCard(String name) {
  dynamic card = findCard(name);

  if (card != null) {
    card.update();
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a function in the constructor of the widget but it tells me that I can't run setState() in the constructor.
It works as a Stateless Widget, but I can't rebuild it every time I call the update() function.

Comment: You want proper state management, because when a value is shared between widgets, things must be coordinated.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: I cannot teach state management in a chat line.  Please google for "state management flutter" and find plenty of information.